# Problem Selecting Items in my Vending Machine c++ program

Tags: c++

I'm sorry, I'm sure that this question has a very simple solution, but I am fairly new to programming and it's been awhile since my last class so I'm rocky on the language. Basically, my teacher walked us through a lot of this project in class, but I've run into this issue and I'm just very sleep deprived and stressed out.

I'm having a problem where when I choose one item from my vending machine program, I can purchase items from that stock just fine, but then once I try to select another item, it just chooses the item I chose the first time again. Here is my code

```
unsigned int vendingMenu(const vector<Item>& items) 
{

// The code to display the menu of the Vending Machine
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) 
{

    Item it = items[i];
    cout << "#=========================================#" << endl;
    cout << "["  << (i + 1) << "] "  << it.itemName 
         << " (" << it.credits << " credits, "
         << it.stock << " in stock)" << endl;

}

cout << "Enter [0] to exit the vending machine" << endl;
cout << "Please select an item: ";

return reader.readInt(0, items.size());

}

void buyItem(unsigned int choice, vector<Item>& items, vector<ItemPurchase>& 
history) 
{

// If the user's option is out of stock, it will output 
// "Sorry, that item is out of stock"
// and bring them back to the menu.

// Otherwise, it'll prompt the user to select how many they want.

if (items[choice - 1].stock == 0) 
{

    cout << "Sorry, that item is out of stock" << endl;

} else 
{

    cout << "You have chosen " << items[choice - 1].itemName
         << " How many " << items[choice - 1].itemName
         << " would you like? (Choose a quantity 0 - " << items[choice - 
1].stock 
         << ")? ";

    unsigned int amount = reader.readInt(0, items[choice - 1].stock);

    if (amount > 0) 
    {

        items[choice - 1].stock -= amount;
        history.push_back(ItemPurchase(items[choice - 1 ].itemName, amount));

    }
}

}

int main() 
{
// A vector of all of the items in the vending machine.
vector<Item> items = 
{

    Item ("Doritos", 180, 11),
    Item ("Cheetos", 150, 14),
    Item ("Lays", 175, 17),
    Item ("Coke Cola", 140, 9),
    Item ("Pepsi", 100, 20),
    Item ("Rockstars", 250, 15),
    Item ("Test Item", 100, 1)

};

vector<ItemPurchase> history;

unsigned int choice = vendingMenu(items);

// When the user chooses '0', it will stop the purchase process.
while (1)
{

buyItem(choice, items, history);
vendingMenu(items);

if (choice == 0)
{
    cout << "Exiting Menu" << endl;
    break;
}

}

buyItem(choice, items, history);

return 0;
}
```

Our professor gave us a file called "CinReader" to prevent the user from doing things like entering a number out of range, or a value that isn't an integer. So that's what all the reader stuff is, and I can post the code for that too if needed.

I know there is some other stuff to be worked out, but I'm just trying to get this problem ironed out first.

And anything you see relating to purchase history is because I also need to make the program output a history of all items purchased in that session once to user exits. I just haven't really gotten to that yet.

Thanks for reading! Any help appreciated.

Comment: The bug is here `vendingMenu(items);` You did it correctly the first time but not this time. This time you throw away whatever the user selected.

Comment: Why are you calling buyitem after exiting the loop?

Comment: @drescherjm thank you! I fixed it by changing that line to choice = vendingMenu(items); (if anyone comes here for a solution to a similar problem)

Comment: @stark that was just leftover from before I put the loop. Thanks for pointing it out